# integer to a binary list in LISP using recursion

Tags: list, recursion, binary, lisp

Recursive function that takes an integer and creates a binary list.

i don't understand why, if (binList 5) will output (1 0 1) which is correct, and the code for (binList 10) leads to (append (binlist 5) '(0)) doesn't give me (1 0 1 0), but gives me (1 1 0 0). I even wrote the same idea in Java, and it worked out. Does recursion work differently in Lisp? or is there something i am missing?

```
(defun binList(N)
    (cond 
        ((< N 1) '())
        ((= N 1) '(1))
        ((> N 1) (if(=(mod N 2) 0) 
                      (append (binList(/ N 2)) '(0))
                      (append (binList(floor(/ N 2))) '(1))))))
```

Comment: Using repeated calls of `APPEND` to add an element to the end of a singly-linked list is *bad*. Try to find out why that is. Add new elements to the front of a singly-linked list.

Answer (score 0):

You code actually produces correct result:

```
CL-USER> (binlist 10)
(1 0 1 0)
```

Just a couple of comments:

- Please, use Lisp name conventions: CL is case insensitive, so `binList` is just `BINLIST`, not too bad here, but `bin-list` would be better.
- The check `(> n 1)` is redundant.

With this comments in mind, the code will look:

```
(defun bin-list(n)
  (cond ((< n 1) '())
        ((= n 1) '(1))
        ((zerop (mod n 2)) (append (bin-list (/ n 2)) '(0)))
        (t (append (bin-list (floor (/ n 2))) '(1)))))
```

The first thing to do, if a recursive code gives you unexpected results, is to trace it:

```
CL-USER> (trace bin-list)
(BIN-LIST)
CL-USER> (bin-list 10)
  0: (BIN-LIST 10)
    1: (BIN-LIST 5)
      2: (BIN-LIST 2)
        3: (BIN-LIST 1)
        3: BIN-LIST returned (1)
      2: BIN-LIST returned (1 0)
    1: BIN-LIST returned (1 0 1)
  0: BIN-LIST returned (1 0 1 0)
(1 0 1 0)
```

As you've pointed out, `(bin-list 10)` results in `(append (bin-list 5) '(0))`. Here you can see the original call (call 0) `(bin-list 10)` leads to call `(bin-list 5)` (call 1). Call 1 returns `(1 0 1)`. And finally, call 0 appends `0` a the end.

If that didn't work, then you can invoke a debugger: see [this blog](http://malisper.me/2015/07/07/debugging-lisp-part-1-recompilation/) for a tutorial on Common Lisp debugger (with SLIME).